# Imaginary Transmission

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, two-level-system

Note that the exact context of Rydberg EIT in the following is, I believe, unimportant.

In the paper "Nonlinear quantum optics mediated by Rydberg interactions," O. Firstenberg et al. (J. Phys. B. 49 (2016)), the authors state that the susceptibility of a two-level system is

$$ \chi = \frac{1}{kl_a} \frac{i\gamma}{\gamma - i\Delta_p}. $$

where $k$ and $l_a$ are unimportant factors, $\gamma$ is the decoherence rate of the excited state, and $\Delta_p$ is the detuning of the ("probe") light field from the atomic transition. In a rough sense, I see where this comes from. Then they elaborate on three-level susceptibility and the possibility for EIT; later, they discuss Rydberg EIT, and they state that, after excitation of a Rydberg atom, within the blockade radius "the transmission amplitude for other photons crossing this blockade sphere is thus given by the bare two-level response

$$ t(\Delta_p) = \exp\left( -\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - i\Delta_p} \frac{\text{OD}_b}{2} \right). $$

"Here the optical depth of the blockade sphere $\text{OD}_b=2r_b/l_a$ depends on the sphere diameter $2r_b$ and the attenuation length $l_a$. ... For an off-resonant probe, $t(|\Delta_p| \gg \gamma) \approx e^{i\phi}$ yields no loss and a conditional phase of $\phi = -(\text{OD}_b/2)(\gamma/\Delta_p)$, thus rendering a dispersive nonlinearity."

I have two questions relating to this passage:

(1) How, *mathematically,* do the authors go from $\chi$ to $t$? I'm not so worried about the factors of the optical depth, $l_a$, and so on; I'm more interested in the $\gamma/(\gamma-i\Delta_p)$ part, and where the $i$ went between $\chi$ and $t$.

(2) What does it mean for *transmission* to have a phase shift? I understand the electric field having a phase shift, but doesn't this go away when you take the modulus squared, which you need for the transmission?